# How to import SQL function in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I use Hibernate and Postgres.
I'm working on completely new project so it's convenient for me to delegate database creation to Hibernate and just verifying it's structure if needed.
During my development I configured hibernate to always delete and create tables when the app starts. I use import.sql to load initial data. I'd like to create a function in postgres.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION someFunction() RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT count(*) > 0 FROM user);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I'd like this to be imported by Hibernate on startup.
However hibernate is not able to handle it due to this: $$

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 61 in SQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION someFunction() RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT count(*) > 0 FROM user). Expected terminating $$
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Same question with a great answer: [postgresql-jpa-import-functions-in-import-sql-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237165/postgresql-jpa-import-functions-in-import-sql-file)