# Unterminated dollar quote init script with testcontainers

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, testcontainers, spring-data-jdbc

I have an init script to be executed on testcontainers (postgres) startup.
My setup is:

- spring boot
- spring data jdbc
- testcontainers on docker
- postgresql

All framworks are up to date as of today.

This is an excerpt of the script:

```
create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT count(*) FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus and NEW.subject = ausr.subject)
        >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

When i fire my test, then this stack trace occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer' defined in de.thd.awp.TestDataSourceConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #30 of class path resource [schema.sql]: create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN IF(SELECT count(*) FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus and NEW.subject = ausr.subject) >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!'; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 91 in SQL create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN IF(SELECT count(*) FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus and NEW.subject = ausr.subject) >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!'. Expected terminating $$
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.1.jar:1.7.1]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #30 of class path resource [schema.sql]: create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN IF(SELECT count(*) FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus and NEW.subject = ausr.subject) >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!'; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 91 in SQL create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN IF(SELECT count(*) FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus and NEW.subject = ausr.subject) >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!'. Expected terminating $$
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.execute(DataSourceInitializer.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializer.java:96) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 91 in SQL create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$ BEGIN IF(SELECT count(*) FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus and NEW.subject = ausr.subject) >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!'. Expected terminating $$
    at org.postgresql.core.Parser.checkParsePosition(Parser.java:1328) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.Parser.parseSql(Parser.java:1227) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.Parser.replaceProcessing(Parser.java:1179) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.CachedQueryCreateAction.create(CachedQueryCreateAction.java:43) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutorBase.createQueryByKey(QueryExecutorBase.java:337) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:300) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar:42.2.19]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

May it be that this is some script-building-voodoo-escaping error?
Or do i have to escape some parts of the script?
Thank you in advance

**EDIT**
I try to initialize the docker/testcontainers/postgres db with a Spring Boot Test Resources `schema.sql` and `DataSourceInitializer`:

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSourceInitializer testDataSourceInitializer() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/schema.sql"));

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(testDataSource());
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
```

Comment: where, when and how do you run this script? is it an sql file within the project or some init method with jdbc invocation or something else?

Comment: according to the log, for some reason not whole the function's text has been recognized as a script to be executed

Comment: Thank you. I´ve edited my post. Hope this helps. I think the `$$` is somehow a problem for the script interpreter. But that´s just a suggestion

Comment: Yuriy Tsarkov is right, ResourceDatabasePopulator splits your big sql script into parts using `;` separator and tries to execute them one by one. This breaks your storage procedure declaration. Take a look at this method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ResourceDatabasePopulator.html#setSeparator-java.lang.String-

Comment: There is already another question concerning this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911065/spring-and-mysql-stored-procedure So i will try both solutions. Place the file under docker initdb and use double ;; as delimiter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring and MySQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911065/spring-and-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: Thank you. I´ve chosen the solution with the built in testcontainer´s init script. Works perfect!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unterminated dollar quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596620/unterminated-dollar-quote)

Comment: I could solve it using the answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/67787882/7320372

Answer (score 3):

Things went very strange when adding a second trigger:

```
create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    IF(SELECT count(*) FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus and NEW.subject = ausr.subject)
        >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$;
```

This leads to another `Unterminated dollar quote` even if i use the same notation with the first trigger where everything works fine.

So found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55596701/7320372

My problem is solved after using `'` as `$$` replacement like so:

```
create or replace function check_registration_limits() returns trigger
as
'
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT count(*)
        FROM applicationusersubjectregistration ausr
        WHERE NEW.campus = ausr.campus
          and NEW.subject = ausr.subject)
        >= (SELECT s.maxparticipants FROM subject s WHERE s.subjectid = NEW.subject) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION ''Registration limits reached! No more voting allowed!'';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
' language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using postgresql, you could try to put the initialization script under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d as explained [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

Answer (score 1):

I´ve left out the above `DataSourceInitializer` bean since testcontainers provide an init script as well.
So my solution is configuring this init script properly with the testcontainer`s postgres container:

```
@Bean
        @Primary
        DataSource testDataSource() {

            if (POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER == null) {
                PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>();
                container.withInitScript("schema.sql");
                container.start();
                POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER = container;
            }
            PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl(POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl());
            dataSource.setUser(POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.getUsername());
            dataSource.setPassword(POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER.getPassword());

            return dataSource;


        }
```

`container.withInitScript("schema.sql");` does the job. Please mind that `schema.sql` has to be placed in `.\src\test\resources`